# Replace semicolon, id and equal sign in URL in an Angular2 app

Tags: json, angular, url, routes

I am trying to set URLs to my items got via `json`.

So I have a structure like that:

```
  <div class="releases-component">
     <div *ngFor="let release of releases" [routerLink]="['/releases', { id:release.id }]">
      <img src="{{release.image}}" alt="Image release">
      <h3>{{release.name}}</h3>
      <span>{{release.year}}</span> 
     </div>
    </div>
```

And I've got `json` of type:

```
[
    {
      "id":"release-1",
      "name": "Release1 name",
      "image": "./cover1.jpg",
      "year": "2014"
    },
    {
      "id":"release-2",
      "name": "Release2 name",
      "image": "./release2.jpg",
      "year": "2015"
    }
]
```

My router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'releases', component: ReleasesComponent },
  { path: 'distro', component: DistroComponent },
  { path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent }
];
```

The problem is that when I click on any `*ngFor` generated div I get url like

```
http://localhost:3000/releases;id=release-1
```

And I want it to look like

```
http://localhost:3000/releases/release-1
```

Didn't manage to find a working solution in Angular2 to me.

Comment: make path to `releases/:id` instead of just `releases`

Comment: @Adeebbasheer Then console throws the Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'releases/releases/%3Aid;id=release-1'

Comment: try this `[routerLink]="['/releases/'+release.id ]"`

Comment: Similar error - Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'releases'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few small syntax mistakes in the code above, here is the code with the fixes.
Structure:

```
<div class="releases-component">
     <div *ngFor="let release of releases" [routerLink]="['/releases',release.id ]">
      <img src="{{release.image}}" alt="Image release">
      <h3>{{release.name}}</h3>
      <span>{{release.year}}</span> 
     </div>
    </div>
```

Router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'releases/:id', component: ReleasesComponent },
  { path: 'distro', component: DistroComponent },
  { path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent }
];
```

Here is a one page similar working example plunkr code: http://plnkr.co/edit/UyNkK9?p=preview,
you can see the url changes on this plunkr url,
http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/UyNkK9/

Here is how the url will look after you click on releases, http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/UyNkK9/releases/release-1

Comment: Thanx! The main point appeared that I also need to include { path: 'releases/:id', component: ReleasesComponent } together with { path: 'releases", component: ReleasesComponent } and it works!

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div class="releases-component">
  <div *ngFor="let release of releases"
  (click)=onSelect(release)>
    <img src="{{release.image}}" alt="Image release">
    <h3>{{release.name}}</h3>
    <span>{{release.year}}</span>
  </div
</div>
```

routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'releases/:id', component: ReleasesComponent },
  { path: 'distro', component: DistroComponent },
  { path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent }
];
```

component:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
...
...

constructor(private router: Router) {}

onSelect(release): any {
  this.router.navigate(['/release', release.id]);
}
```

Comment: Console throws Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'releases/release-1' So at least it changed the error to the right look) Will try to get the thing where I am doing wrong